# How to use less CPU in a thread (mainly) responsible for publishing

Tags: c#, queue, real-time, infinite-loop, zeromq

When using an infinite loop to `tryDequeue` a queue, it uses too much CPU.

Is it possible to make this operation to execute as a User Interface notification,
when the queue is not empty? And then run it an event or function?

I reached the conclusion that in my implementation that uses the ZeroMQ library, in the  thread mainly responsible for publishing, the infinite loop can not be avoided.

```
using (var context = new Context(1)){
                    using (Socket client = context.Socket(SocketType.PUB)){
while (!StopAllThread){
   SQLQueue.TryDequeue(out message);
   if (message != null){
   ...
   }
}
}
```

Comment: What is that `SqlQueue` type?

Comment: I think you should be using a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx) along with `GetConsumingEnumerable()` and `foreach` to wait for and process items from the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what API or technology you use, but I would guess there should be a blocking alternative, such as

```
var message = SQLQueue.Dequeue();
```

In general case this will block a thread until a message is read from a queue. This shall not consume any CPU when there is nothing to read.

If you use Zeromq (from comment) there is a blocking call on the server ([taken from here](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq))

```
// ZMQ Context, server socket
using (ZmqContext context = ZmqContext.Create())
using (ZmqSocket server = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.REP))
{
    server.Bind("tcp://*:5555");

    while (true)
    {
        // Wait for next request from client
        string message = server.Receive(Encoding.Unicode);
        ...
```

#### Comments

If you change your architecture from active polling for a new message to push based model you will get rid of the problem of high CPU consumption. In a push model you have one thread reading from a queue. It blocks if there is no message there. Once a message is read your code dispatches an event to the consumer, saying that a new message was read, and here is the message for the consumer to handle.

Have a look at [`Blocking Collection Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287085.aspx) method.

Comment: using Zeromq, there is a thread only responsible for publish and looping to check the queue whether empty, if not empty then send

Comment: `TryDequeue` seems like method of `ConcurrentQueue` I don't think `ConcurrentQueue` has a `Dequeue` method!

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It may not be. `ConcurrentQueue` can be wrapped up as a `BlockinCollection` and then there is a blocking [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287085.aspx). It looks like this is a member of `Zeromq`

Comment: the thread has only publish, no receive, how concurrentqueue become blocking ?

Comment: @Galois you can change `ConcurrentQueue` to `BlockingCollection` and use Take method.

Comment: It might be application specific. Just start with a value you comfortable with, say 5 seconds. If your app runs 25/7, this seems like a reasonable timeout.

Answer (score 2):

The [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx) is useful for this kind of thing.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Program
    {
        private readonly BlockingCollection<string> _queue = new BlockingCollection<string>();

        private void run()
        {
            Task.Run(() => producer());
            consumer();

            Console.WriteLine("Press <return> to exit.");
        }

        private void consumer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("consumer() starting.");

            foreach (var item in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("consumer() processing item " + item);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("consumer() stopping.");
        }

        private void producer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("producer() starting.");

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
            {
                _queue.Add(i.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("producer() finishing.");

            _queue.CompleteAdding(); // Calling this makes the consumer exit its foreach loop.
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().run();
        }

    }
}
```

Notice how you can call `GetConsumingEnumerable()` to get an enumerable which automatically blocks when waiting for new items to appear in the queue, but which finishes immediately when the queue is marked as completed via a call to `CompleteAdding()` in the producer thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the `Queue` to add some event, then you can handle the event to notify about enqueueing and dequeueing items:

```
public class CustomQueue<T> : Queue<T>
{
    public event EventHandler ItemDequeued;
    public event EventHandler ItemEnqueued;
    public new void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        base.Enqueue(item);
        if (ItemEnqueued != null) ItemEnqueued(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public new T Dequeue()
    {
        T a = base.Dequeue();
        if (ItemDequeued != null) ItemDequeued(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        return a;
    }
}
//Then you can handle the event ItemDequeued to know if its Count = 0
yourQueue.ItemDequeued += (s, e) =>{
   if (yourQueue.Count == 0) MessageBox.Show("EMPTY queue!");
};
yourQueue.ItemEnqueued += (s,e) => {
   //you can try running code asynchronously here;
};
```

Comment: event trigger is good, however, the zeromq connection have to be continous exist, the infinite loop seems can not be avoided

Comment: @Galois you can do everything with `event`, why do you think this is related to `zeromq connection`?